# Cloning and appending a div

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to clone a div and all of its children, and append the clone onto the end of the original when the user clicks a button and change the `id` of child element, but for some reason I can't even get my `div` to clone and append.

```
<div id="section">
    //bunch of textboxes, labels, etc.
</div>
```

Here is my button

```
<input type="button" value="Add New Section" id="addSection"/>
```

Here is my Jquery

```
$(function() {
    var $section = $("#section").clone();  

    $( "#addSection" ).click(function() { 
        $section.append(); // I've tried this and appendTo, Insert, InstertAfter, After, etc.. still cannot get this to work.. 
    });
});
```

Ignore the fact that this doesn't change any child element id's, why is this not cloning and appending?

**EDIT**

I guess to clarify, I am trying to clone the original state of my div and append that every time my button is clicked.

Comment: 1) Use `appendTo()` 2) Add a selector as argument.

Comment: Append to what? You need to specify selector to append the element. For ex. `$('#section').append($section)`

Comment: I assume you want the clone button to work repeatedly, and not just once. Yes?

Comment: @showdev yes it needs to work more then once

Comment: and the downvote was for?

Comment: @BigRabbit Then I'm confused why you accepted the answer from ShaunakD and not PaulRoub.

Comment: @showdev Ah, just noticed that, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the content in jQuery's append function.

Ex -

> $('#YOUR_ELEMENT_ID').append('YOUR_CONTENT')

Here it will be like,

```
$(function() {    
  var $section = $("#section").clone(); 
    $( "#addSection" ).click(function() { 
        var $sectionClone = $section.clone();
        $('#section').append($sectionClone); 
    });
});
```

Working Demo [HERE](http://jsbin.com/tanomaqiqe/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I need everything to be cloned prior to my click so this doesn't work for me.

Comment: What you want to clone. ? Everything means ?

Comment: I think the OP means that he doesn't want the *cloned* content to be cloned -- just the original content. With your code, the appended content grows longer each time it is cloned.

Comment: Oh..maybe I had not understood what he wanted exactly at first. Anyway, I have edited the answer now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to insert the cloned section *after* the original, we'd want to clone on the `click` (not before), so this will work if called more than once.

Then we replace the `id` (I'm using the current time to make the id unique, you could do something else), and `insertAfter()` to place it after our original element:

```js
$("#addSection").click(function() {

  var section = $("#section").clone();

  section.attr('id', 'section' + (new Date()).getTime());

  section.insertAfter( $('#section') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section">
  <p>bunch of textboxes, labels, etc.</p>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Add New Section" id="addSection" />
```

Comment: I need it to be cloned with its original content that is why I was running the clone before my click, but I need my button to work multiple times

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a selector to append the element to.

```
$('#section').append($section)
```

Or

```
$section.appendTo('#section')
```

Or use `.after()` to insert the cloned element after the original.

```
$('#section').after($section)
```

*Edit* : You need to clone the element after click to make it work everytime.

So integrated function,

```
$(function(){
    $( "#addSection" ).click(function(){
        var $section = $("#section").clone();  
        $section.attr('id','someUniqueId');
        $('#section').after($section); 
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L2dvqojr/)

Comment: This only clones and appends once, I need it to work multiple times

Comment: I dont think it would clone multiple times of you init the cloned section before click.

Comment: Ok, how would I clone my div with its original contents, and append it each time my button is clicked?

Comment: @ShaunakD I still get the problem of it cloning any content that was added to the div with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
  var $section = $("#section").clone();  

  $( "#addSection" ).click(function() { 
    $("#section").append($section);
  });
});
```

Comment: This will only clone once. Also, a description of your solution would be helpful.

Comment: @showdev Did you test that claim? I had it append every time i clicked the button on plunker.

Comment: [Yes, I did](http://jsfiddle.net/4qpd04kh/). It might be helpful to provide a runnable snippet (or link to) your working version.